Excel Conditional Formatting - If Date Z Within XX Days of Date Y
i’m trying to set up conditional formatting where a cell is highlighted if a date in Cell A1 is within 40 days of date in Cell A2. Any help appreciated!
Tried IF(A1=A2+40). Seen lots of example using TODAY function but i need it to be against a date in another cell, not today.


=ABS(A1-A2)<40 ?

if a date in Cell A1 is within 40 days of date in Cell A2 What about AND(A1>=A2;A1<=(A2+40))

Try custom CF-
=AND(($B1-$A1)>0,($B1-$A1)<40)



Thank you, I think that works! Is there any way to use this formula but for the cell reference to change? I’m on my phone so a bit difficult to explain but if you can imagine a matrix - weeks across the top and changing dates going down the side, I need the formula to account changing dates in row 1 and changing dates in column A. The help is much appreciated. It might not be possible without a macro.

@MEGANORMEROD Better post few of your sample data to your post and then show your desired output.

I've added a picture if you can see that?

If a Task takes 40 days. I am trying to use conditional formatting to highlight a cell where the forecast date in column B is within 40 days/8 weeks of the dates in row 1, but obviously where the dates in column B and row 1 are then changing. I have done the formatting manually here but the real data set is very big, so trying to do it automatically.

Plz try this as a formula, changing as appropriate depending where your data starts:
=LET(diff,$B2-C$1,(diff>=0)*(diff<=40))

or
=LET(diff,$B2-C$1,and(diff>=0,diff<=40)

if you prefer.


There may be variations on this (perhaps using Networkdays) if you need 8 working weeks or calendar weeks).

Please use AND() instead of multiplication of booleans.

Maybe it's a bit cryptic, will add alternative to my answer.
